# Change innerHTML every 5 seconds using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am creating a simple website and I want to change the header's blank fill with random word every 5 seconds.

Here is the boilerplate to start

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.header')
const needs = ['jacket', 'umbrella', 'sunscreen', 'sunglasses', 'air cooler']
```

What basically I want to achieve is to set one word of the `needs` as text of the `.header` element every % seconds, totally random. I want it to create it with Vue.js and not vue-cli beacuse the setInterval makes the page lag like hell.
Please help me because I have no Idea how to do this. 
How can I implement something like this in Vue:

```js
   setInterval(()=>{
   header.innerHTML = needs[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Okay, so you want stack overflow users to make a vue component for you? What have you tried?

Comment: Check this and help me 'cause I am new to Vue

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this is definitely not how vue works. Please take a look (5 to 10 minutes) at the excellent vue documentation at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ you'll find answer to that question in the introduction page. So the setInterval work, but modifying a variable in your instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple component for your requirement would look like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="header">{{ word }}</div>
</template>

<script>
const words = ["jacket", "umbrella", "sunscreen", "sunglasses", "air cooler"];

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data: function() {
    return {
      word: ""
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateWord: function() {
      this.word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    }
  },

  mounted: function() {
    this.updateWord();
    setInterval(this.updateWord, 5000);
  }
};
</script>
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-array-random-xzlor?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).
And take a look at the Vue documentation at [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide), please.

Answer (score 1):

For those that just want to loop through the words.

```
<div>{{words[i}}</div>

 data() {
    return {
      words: ["jacket", "umbrella", "sunscreen", "sunglasses", "air cooler"],
      i: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.i < this.words.length-1) this.i++
      else this.i = 0
    },5000)
  }
```